# Why do we use headers in REST API, when we are already mentioning the method as POST?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

my question is about - when we use the same REST API for information exchange for other tools, we don't mention headers, x-httpmethod & x-requestdigest there.

But in case of SharePoint, why don't the request would be directly DELETE - but we do mention in headers as x-httpmethod?

Answer (score 0):

Below explanation should answer your question.

> It is possible to instruct network intermediaries (proxies, firewalls,
>   and so on) inspecting traffic at the application protocol layer (for
>   example, HTTP) to block requests that contain certain HTTP verbs. In
>   practice, GET and POST verbs are rarely blocked (traditional web pages
>   rely heavily on these HTTP methods), while, for a variety of reasons
>   (such as security vulnerabilities in prior protocols), other HTTP
>   methods (PUT, DELETE, and so on) are at times blocked by
>   intermediaries. Additionally, some existing HTTP libraries do not
>   allow creation of requests using verbs other than GET or POST.
>   Therefore, an alternative way of specifying request types which use
>   verbs other than GET and POST is needed to ensure that this document
>   works well in a wide range of environments.
>
> To address this need, the X-HTTP-Method header can be added to a POST
>   request that signals that the server MUST process the request not as a
>   POST, but as if the HTTP verb specified as the value of the header was
>   used as the method on the HTTP request's request line, as specified in
>   [RFC2616] section 5.1. This technique is often referred to as "verb
>   tunneling".

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541471.aspx